# Integrating charge from known current

Tags: current, charge

So I'm given a parametric formula for current measured across an ideal basic circuit element. It is \$i = 0 A\$ at \$t < 0\$ and \$ i = 20e^{-5000t} A\$ at \$ t\ge0\$ (t being time, in seconds). I'm then asked to calculate the total charge at the higher potential terminal.

The book lists the answer as \$4000\mu C\$. When I integrate the current equation, though, I use U-substitution (\$u=-5000t\$) and come out with \$ (-\frac {20}{5000}e^{-5000t}) + (\frac {20}{5000}) \$.

What step am I missing?

Comment: Also, it's possible that this is just a simple math problem, but the Calc tutor wasn't quite sure what to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing that you have to integrate over a period of time, you solved the integral but now you have to calculate the value of charge accumulated. As the current will never stop you have to integrate all the way up to infinity.

So it's \$I(\infty)\$ - \$I(0)\$ = 0.004C = 4mC or 4000µC.